# Map API batch stocks object to stocks array | React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api, object

I'm using axios with react to query the alpha vantage api. I have the api part working. What I am trying to figure out is how to map to data I am pulling to make it accessible to generate a list of items from the data. I want to use map create an array called stocks that would then have an object for each item with the symbol, price, volume, timestamp that I could use. How do I correctly do this?

Here's my map function:

```
axios.get(axios.get(url)
.then(res => {
  console.log(res.data['Stock Quotes']);
  const stocks = res.data['Stock Quotes'].map((stock) => [{symbol: stock.symbol, price: stock.price}])
})
.catch(error => console.log(error))
)
```

This is what is returning from the console.log(res.data['Stock Quotes']);

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0:{1. symbol: "MSFT", 2. price: "93.8100", 3. volume: "26478373", 4. timestamp: "2018-03-07 16:00:00"}
1:{1. symbol: "FB", 2. price: "183.7000", 3. volume: "19004961", 4. timestamp: "2018-03-07 16:56:26"}
2:{1. symbol: "AAPL", 2. price: "175.0200", 3. volume: "30982083", 4. timestamp: "2018-03-07 16:36:24"}
length:3
```

This is what is returning from the console.log(stocks);

```
(3) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
0:Array(1)
0:{symbol: undefined, price: undefined}
length:1
__proto__:Array(0)
0:Array(1)
1:{symbol: undefined, price: undefined}
length:1
```

This is the full code I'm using

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import SearchBar from './components/search_bar';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

this.state = {
  stocks: [],
  term: null,
  value: ''
};

this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(e) {
this.setState({
  value: e.target.value
});
}

handleClick(e) {
  if(e) e.preventDefault();

  this.setState({
    value: '',
    term: this.state.value,
    stocks: this.state.stocks
  });

let term = this.state.value;
const key = 'F41ON15LGCFM4PR7';
const url = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=BATCH_STOCK_QUOTES&symbols=${term}&apikey=${key}`;

axios.get(axios.get(url)
.then(res => {
  console.log(res.data['Stock Quotes']);
  const stocks = res.data['Stock Quotes'].map((stock) => [{symbol: stock.symbol, price: stock.price}])
})
.catch(error => console.log(error))
)

}

render () {
const value = this.state.value;
return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Stock Search</h1>
    <SearchBar value={ value }
               onChange={ this.handleChange }
               onClick={ this.handleClick }/>
  </div>
);
}
}
export default App;
```

Comment: even `Array.from(res.data['Stock Quotes']).map(...)` didn't work?

Comment: Just tried that. It generates the same  - undefined @guijob

Comment: @guijob just as a side note, `Array#from` can take a `map` function as a second argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the whole key for each "Stock Quote's" "symbol" is actually `"1. symbol"`, not just `"symbol"` (and for price it's `"2. price"`).

Why this would be the case I have no idea, but the following should work:

```
const stocks = res.data['Stock Quotes'].map((stock) => [{symbol: stock['1. symbol'], price: stock['2. price']}])
```

Comment: Thank you, that's it! I should have figured that out because brackets were required for the ['Stock Quotes'] as well. It is a peculiar little api ...